# signal a slot in another class in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, signals

**Situation**:
I have a `Dialog` class in Qt on which I draw a raster of squares. The squares are implemented in the `MySquare` class (MySquare: QGraphicsItem).

**Question**:
I want to signal the Dialog slot `setTarget()` that a square was clicked (and obviously I want to give it some information about that square like for example it's x and y coordinates with it later). However I get an 'undefined reference to '`MySquare::targetChanged()`' error. I have looked for a solution but have not found any; anybody an idea?

edit: I have added a Q_OBJECT macro inside the MySquare however the error does not dissapear and I get an additional "'undefined reference to '`vtable for MySquare()`' error

*dialog.h*

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

  ~Dialog();


public slots:
    void setTarget();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
};
```

*dialog.cpp*

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    MySquare *item;

    item = new MySquare(30,30,30,30);
    QObject::connect(item,SIGNAL(targetChanged()),this,SLOT(setTarget()));
}

void Dialog::setTarget(){
    qDebug() << "signal recieved" << endl;
}
```

*mysquare.h*

```
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QObject>

class MySquare : public QGraphicsItem, public QObject
{

Q_OBJECT

public:
    MySquare(int x,int y,int h, int w);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    int x,y,h,w;

signals:
    void targetChanged();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
};
```

*mysquare.cpp*

```
#include "mysquare.h"
#include <QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent>
#include <QWidget>

MySquare::MySquare(int _x,int _y, int _w, int _h)
{

    setAcceptDrops(true);
    color=Qt::red;
    color_pressed = Qt::green;
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    w = _w;
    h = _h;
}


QRectF MySquare::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(x,y,w,h); 
}


void MySquare::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QRectF rec = boundingRect();
    QBrush brush(color);

        if (Pressed){
            brush.setColor(color);
        } else {
            brush.setColor(color_pressed);
        }

    painter->fillRect(rec,brush);
    painter->drawRect(rec);
}


void MySquare::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    Pressed=true;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);

    emit targetChanged();
}



void MySquare::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    Pressed=false;
    update();
    QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    qDebug() << "mouse Released";
}

void MySquare::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    qDebug() << "mouse Moved";
    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(event->widget());
    QMimeData *mime = new QMimeData;
    drag->setMimeData(mime);
    drag->exec();
}


void MySquare::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    //out of bounds check?
    int x = pos().x();
    int y = pos().y();

    QGraphicsItem::keyPressEvent(event);

}
```

Comment: no; signals are neither public or private

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking something else.

Comment: You might be better off asking here: http://www.qtcentre.org/forum.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: If you have an undefined reference to a vtable, then it's probably because you did not implement certain virtual functions. Have you implemented the mouse event handlers of the `MySquare` class somewhere? Have you also implemented the `boundingRect()` and `paint()` functions of the `MySquare` class?

Old answer:
You need to write the `Q_OBJECT` macro after the opening '{' in the `MySquare` class. Also Qt will complain about multiple inheritance at some point. Therefore, instead of inheriting from `QGraphicsItem` and `QObject`, inherit from `QGraphicsObject` instead.

The actual reason, the linker complains about a missing function definition is the following: When you put a `Q_OBJECT` macro into the right place, then the Qt Meta Object Compiler (MOC) will generate a new cpp file for the project which contains the definition of the signal  functions of the respective class. So Qt implements a function for every signal for you. If you don't insert the `Q_OBJECT` macro, then MOC won't do anything for you and the function definition for the signal will be missing to the linker.

Comment: in the header or cpp file? I had already put the Q_OBJECT maco in the header file so I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: answer to edit: yes I did; and that code worked just fine before I added any signals& slots; the only function that is not defined is targetChanged() but I guess I don't have to because it's a signal? edit: yes these functions are also defined as you can see in the header files; I will post the code for the MySquare class to in my post

Comment: New edit: Have you implemented `boundingRect()` and `paint()`?

Comment: Yes I have; I'm now editing my question to include the cpp file from mysquare

Comment: Ok. I see. Well, then I cannot see why the linker complains. Are there more detailed diagnostics, like a concrete hint for a missing function reference? Maybe you can try to make your linker more verbose on what's missing.

Comment: Yes After running qmake the errors have changed: to 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of QGraphicsItem and a number of other similar errors

Comment: Try to inherit primarily from `QObject` and secondarily from `QGraphicsItem`. Or even better: inherit only from `QGraphicsObject`. Qt doesn't like multiple inheritance with QObject very much. Does this help?

Comment: yes; that does it; thank you very much; could you please add it to you answer. class MySquare : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem did the trick

Comment: I did in the middle paragraph.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by ' Therefore, use QGraphicsObject for it.'

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following steps:

Build-clean
Build-run qmake
Build-build.

Maybe the moc Option is not Set in the Makefile after you added the Q_Object Makro. Therefore you have to refresh your Makefile.

Hope this helps.